# Implementing Iterable

Tags: scala, iterable

How to implement Scala equivalent to Java `Iterable<T>` and C# `IEnumerable<T>`? Basically, I want my collection to be mappable, filterable etc. What traits should the collection class extend and are there easy ways (something like `yield return` and `yield break` in C#) to create enumerator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implement the `Iterable` trait.  All that is required is the `iterator` method.  All the other methods (`map`, `filter`, etc) come for free.

```
class MyIterable[T](xs: Vector[T]) extends Iterable[T] { 
  override def iterator = xs.iterator 
}

val a = new MyIterable(Vector(1,2,3))
a.map(_+1) // res0: Iterable[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
a.filter(_%2==1) // res1: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 3)
```

Comment: whatis the performance burden of that code? meaning: does it take O(n) time?

Comment: @StefanKunze, *what* does take O(n) time? Of course, say, index lookup will be linear. But this is iterable, after all, not indexable.

Comment: the initial conversion to an iterator?

Comment: "converting" to an iterator is constant, since it doesn't have to convert anything.  All it has to do is wrap the vector and advance an index every time `next` is called.

Comment: This code does nothing but overriding the iterator. I don't see how is this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scala.collection.Iterable` trait or its immutable version which are pretty comprehensive and powerful. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the enumerators, there is Enumeration in Scala but using sealed traits + derived classes seems to be more flexible, for example:

```
sealed trait MyEnum {
  lazy val value = 0
}
case object MyEnumA extends MyEnum {
  override lazy val value = 1
}
case object MyEnumB extends MyEnum {
  override lazy val value = 2
}

scala> val a = MyEnumB
a: MyEnumB.type = MyEnumB

scala> a.value
res24: Int = 2

scala>  val l = List(MyEnumA,MyEnumB)
l: List[Product with Serializable with MyEnum] = List(MyEnumA, MyEnumB)

scala> l.map(_.value)
res29: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

You can use these objects without any internal structure as well, if you don't care about mapping them to anything except their string representations:

```
sealed trait MyEnum
case object MyEnumA extends MyEnum
case object MyEnumB extends MyEnum

scala> val a = MyEnumA
a: MyEnumA.type = MyEnumA

scala> a.toString
res21: String = MyEnumA

scala> val l = List(MyEnumA,MyEnumB)
l: List[Product with Serializable with MyEnum] = List(MyEnumA, MyEnumB)

scala> l.map(_.toString)
res30: List[String] = List(MyEnumA, MyEnumB)
```